# How do I remove the space that is automatically added above text?

Tags: css, html

I want the top of "rules" to line up with the top of the image. I added a white border to show that the top of the container lines up fine.

[image: my html]
[image]

Comment: <div style="vertical-align:top;"> <<-- Try this on the div that has the Rules header.

Comment: In future please don't post images of your code, no one is going to re-type it all out to help your debugging

Comment: oh, and you really ought to use css, its far more maintainable than inline styles

Comment: @andrew I didn't want anyone to retype my code. Simply saying what css rule I need is fine. As for the inline css you're correct that it is generally easier, but I find this just as easy and pages that use inline css load faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, paragraphs have a margin at the top of them. You can either add `margin-top: 0;` to the paragraph's styles, or you might want to consider using a CSS reset, which helps normalize element styles.

A good reset stylesheet to use is Eric Meyer's (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), although different people prefer different resets for various reasons.